# How to model a repeating sinc pulse in LTSPICE?

Tags: ltspice, modeling

I'm looking to model a repeating sinc pulse in LTSPICE, however I can only get it to fire once. I'm looking to delay it by x many ms, and trigger the pulse the again.

Is this possible with LTSPICE ?

Comment: you mean sin(x)/x? What are you using for the pulse?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ya sin(x)/x, I'm using a behavioral voltage source (BV)

Comment: A simple sin wave voltage source and a comparator would be my first approximation...

Comment: @Spoon elaborate ?

Comment: @efox29, do you just want a repeating pulse? I know it may seem silly but the Voltage source with Pulse and the following  parameters as an example... PULSE(0 1 0 0 0 0.01 0.1) or a pulse you can adjust to test the sync function of your circuit?

Comment: Also note that there is an "alternate definition" of sinc \$\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}\$ where the zero-crossings occur at integer multiples of \$t\$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just similar to what I wrote in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107391/how-to-create-spice-ltspice-repeatable-damped-sinusoid/160436#160436) you can do almost anything repetitive by using the time variable and a modulus. So let us set this up step by step. First just a sinc function for convenience:

```
.function sinc(x) { sin(x)/x }
```

Using this together with the `time` variable and a little scaling we can get this b source:

```
V=sinc(time*100)
```

to produce this here:

[image]

This isn't repetetive so let us create a modulo function and use that to bring back the parameter into range:

```
.function mod(x,y) { (x/y)-int(x/y) }
V=sinc(mod(time,1)*100)
```

[image]

Better, but not quite nice as the "pulse" starts at 0 of the sinc again. It would be better if it started a bit lower, so lets shift and align it a little bit nicer:

```
V=sinc(mod(time,pi/3)*100-pi)
```

[image]

You should now be able to take this as a starting point to calculate a waveform that matches your needs.

Comment: oh.. em.. gee :o

Comment: perhaps you would want to shift the basic sinc left more

Comment: @Mike: maybe. This is just showing how to do it, the exact amount of shifting and scaling is up to whatever the OP wants in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is helpful in the context of your simulation, but you can produce an approximation to a series of sinc pulses with a slight negative DC bias by simply summing together a set of cosine waves. Start with one at the pulse repetition frequency, and add integer harmonics of that frequency, all at the same amplitude:

$$pulse(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N cos (2\pi i f t)$$

The value you select for N will determine the width of the individual pulses; a higher value will create narrower pulses. Also, as N increases, the peak amplitude of the pulses increases linearly as well; scale by \$\frac{1}{N}\$ if desired.

See an example on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%280.5+*+cos+%282+pi+f+t%29%29+from+f%3D1+to+5)

Comment: You know, it's not the ideal approach because LTSPICE doesn't have a way to sum up multiple terms, but that Wolfram link pointed me in the write direction, that I can just write a macro that will create as many terms as I need and delay it by the value I want. It's a bit more work, but it beats typing out the series with a + in between each term.